# Folder Synchronization via LAN

Tags: sync

i am looking for an application that is like *dropbox*. i simply would like to synchronize my music folder (which is 100 GB) via LAN between my desktop & laptop. (you can see why i cannot use dropbox for there is the size restriction and it will try to upload a bus load of files to its central server)

Comment: i think the right tool is 'rsync'. now i need to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

For bidirectional syncing, try [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (unison-gtk for GUI) from the repositories.

http://www.tecmint.com/file-synchronization-in-linux-using-unison/

https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison